# What is a locally deterministic ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, economics, stability-in-odes

I am reading an [economics paper](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~pschnabl/research/DSS_july2015.pdf) in which the authors write at one point (page 11, section D):

> We restrict attention to policies under which inflation is locally deterministic
>
> $$ -\frac{\mathrm{d}\pi_{t}}{\pi_{t}} = \iota_{t}\mathrm{d}t.$$

What exactly does ***locally*** deterministic mean here? Though I understand it’s an ODE and there are concepts like deterministic or stochastic ODEs (the latter when it contains an additive shock component, for instance), I don’t get what *locally deterministic* is and why they have to assume it. Will also appreciate any suggestions for suitable references on this and related topics, preferably targeted for those in economics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My educated guess is this (to confirm it, I would probably need to invest quite some time to dig into that paper):*

The authors know that the dynamics they investigate is stochastic, but they assume that on short time scales (“locally”), it can be treated like a deterministic dynamics governed by the given equation. So, they do not claim that the equation leads to some special dynamics that has a miraculous property of being locally deterministic. Instead, the equation (which is deterministic) is a local description of the dynamics.

If I understand the paper correctly from my quick glance, $ι_t$ is the inflation rate.
This may be subject to stochastic fluctuations on large time scales, but this is not relevant for modelling processes that happen on a scale of days.
On such a time scale, it is probably a valid assumption that this rate is constant – and thus the dynamics is deterministic.

Comment: Thanks, @Wrzlprmft. I reckon you are right. It's clearer to me now what they are doing -- probably for reasons of tractability, they are modelling inflation as a locally deterministic ODE, rather than as a stochastic process.